# How to remeber when user last visted website in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would to remember when user last visited my website. I see following options:

1. Remember last login time and disabling remember cookie
2. Save information after every request in Database

Both options are not far from ideal solution.

Comment: Did you consider a database option? Saving that information in some sort of database ...

Comment: @Kaz-LA save information in every request was talking about DB!

Comment: @Kaz-LA I updated point 2

Comment: You can save the information to database during authentication/login time(once) not on every request ....

Comment: @Kaz-LA but if I allow to remember cookie won't happened every visit. For example in StackOverflow I last logged in a month ago. But I visit site almost every day.

Comment: @Garath You can provide a daily cookie, that lives from 24 h. Every day he logs in you give this cookie to the user. If your user doens't got this, log the last visited and then create the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cookie that will hold the information about the last day that someone visited your web site. For exemple:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["last-visited"] == null)
    {
        /*Log if the user visited you app here somewhere, data base etc*/

        /*Create a cookie to hold that you already logged this visit*/
        var lastVisitedCookie = new HttpCookie("last-visited");
        lastVisitedCookie.Expires.AddDays(1);

        Response.Cookies.Add(lastVisitedCookie);
    }
}
```

To secure your cookie, you can put something encrypted inside to make sure that It's generated for your app, not for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use some sort of state to keep this information in, you won't be able to get away from it.

You options are as you said, database or cookies.

I would use database if you need to know who the user is, and a cookie if you don't care, but just need to know they have been before.